# terminal printing text repeatedly without stop in valet ping foo.dev

Tags: php, valet

My terminal prints and doesn't stop printing the following code after `ping foo.dev` using valet:

```
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.133 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
```

Everything has been properly installed with not a single error up until this point.

Why is my terminal spitting out this code?

Comment: if using Linux or Unix terminal click control + C when you're done with ping, it stops it... or you can ping -c 5 foo.dev to perform 5 pings and stop

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a *nix as windows `ping` has a default counter of 3

If you were to look at the manual you would see there is a count param for `ping`

So try

```
ping -c 2 xxx.com
```

to do just 2 pings

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's because ping command goes indefinitely when called alone with no parameters specifying number of pings to perform.

If using Linux, Unix, you could press Control + C to stop the pings.
If using Windows, Control + Break will stop it.

Or you could simply add parameters with ping "ping -c X foo.dev" where X is the number of pings you would like to perform.